# I need to get Public IPv4 address and decrypted key pair on response of newly created instance by boto3 Lambda Function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

****I need to get Public IPv4 address and decrypted key pair on response of newly created instance by boto3 Lambda Function?**

I am creating a instance using boto3 and i want to print the public ip Address and decrypted key (password) on **response**. please assist to complete this code

```
import boto3
import json
 
AMI = 'AMI'
INSTANCE_TYPE = 'INSTANCE_TYPE'
KEY_NAME = 'KEY_NAME'
REGION = 'REGION'
SUBNET_ID = 'SUBNET_ID'
SECURITYGROUP_ID = 'SECURITYGROUP_ID'
 

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=event['REGION'])
     
    instance = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId=event['AMI'],
        InstanceType=event['INSTANCE_TYPE'],
        KeyName=event['KEY_NAME'],
        SubnetId=event['SUBNET_ID'],
        SecurityGroupIds = ['my.sg'],
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior="terminate",
        TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'instance',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'myserver'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    )
    
    print ("New instance created:")
    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    print (instance_id)
 
    return instance_id
```

please correct the code

```
 ip = new_instance[0].private_ip_address
    public_ip = new_instance[0].public_ip_address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a little bit of time after an instance has been launched for a **Public IP address** to be assigned to the instance.

It takes a LONG time for a **Windows password** to be available on a newly launched instance.

Thus, your function **will need to wait** until that information is available. It can either keep calling `describe_instances()` and check the values, or can use a [waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning). However, the instance status is not necessarily an indication of whether the Windows password is avilable.

Note that waiting for data to be available is not ideal for an AWS Lambda function because you are charged for the duration that the function runs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John Rotenstein can u please suggest the code for this ..

Comment: As mentioned, you would need to repeatedly call `describe_instances()` until it returns a public IP address. (Don't call it too often -- maybe wait 10 seconds between retries.) Windows passwords can be retrieved via `get_password_data()`, however it can take several minutes to become available. Using Step Functions might be a better approach, since it can wait between calling Lambda functions so you're not paying for waiting time, but it is a more complex solution.

Comment: Hi @John Rotenstein can u please suggest the code for print public ip itself on response column

Comment: After calling `response = describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])`, check if there is a value for `response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['PublicIpAddress']`